# Installed Subversion but I don't see repos via the web UI

Tags: svn, svnserve

I installed Subversion on linux.  The repository I created is in /root/.  I did this command as root: svnserve -d

I see a svnserve daemon running in the processes (with a ps -ef | grep svn).  However, I cannot access the repository via a web browser.  Via the workstation that I connect to the Linux server with Putty, I open a web browser.  In the browser I go to (with an http:// in front of) these URLs fullyqualifieddomainname/nameOfRepo and hostname/nameOfRepo.  I don't see anything with either URL.  I killed the svnserve process.  I started it again, and tried browsing to it.  I have never been able to see via a web broswer my new Subversion repository in a newly installed Subversion instance.  How do I access Subversion via a web UI?

I tried svnserve -i

That didn't work either.

Does Subversion need anonymous access for web browsing?  I'm not getting any message when I browse to it via a web browser.  That's why it doesn't seem to be a permissions issue (with anonymous access).  What all needs to be configured to permit Subversion to be accessible via a web browser?  (Should I check something in IP tables?  Do I need ViewVC?)

Answer (score 1):

There is no web interface exposed when you use svnserve. You need to use HTTP to serve your repository, or install a web-based repository browser like ViewVC.